# Are all Equations Functions?

Tags: functions

**Are all Equations Functions?**

That is, does an Equation always imply a Function?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? An equation is completely different from a function.

Comment: Relations defined by some equality of the type $f(x, y) = 0 \iff x\,\rho\, y$ where function $f$ is given, aren't necessarily functions.

Comment: See the post [Transforming equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167334/transforming-equations-rules-governing-the-use-of-and) : equations are mathematical exprsssions using equality. They usually use functions, like $+, \times$.

Answer (score 1):

No, an equation just states that two things are equal. If an equation can correspond to a mapping between variables, only then is it a function

For example, $\quad x=x,\quad1=1, \quad2+2=4\quad$ are all identities, i.e. equations that are always true, and are not functions.

But $y=x$,$\quad$ $x^2=y+z$ can all be interpreted as functions, as they show relationships between variables which can be used for mapping one variable to another.

Comment: Sweet, that made perfect sense. Thanks you aman.