# Name of the arithmetic property if a=b then a+c = b+c?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Properties of arithmetic operations such multiplication and division have names. For example:

$a + b = b + a$ (commutativity)

$(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ associativity

and so on

is there a name for

if $a=b$ then $a+c = b+c$ ?

Comment: I would just call it a mathematical syllogism

Comment: Closely related [Does "Doing a thing to both sides of an equation" have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570986/242)  See esp. my comments on the (misleading) accepted answer there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it has a name. It's just a special case of $a=b\implies f(a)=f(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Adding $c$ to both sides of an equation is a so-called "equivalence transformation" ; that is a transformation that does not change the set of solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a name. The converse rule, however:
$$
a + c = b + c\implies a = b
$$
is called cancellation. You could argue that your rule is in some sense cancellation for subtraction, but it takes more work than it's worth, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the generalization would be monotonicity of addition:

$$a\leq b\Rightarrow a+c\leq b+c.$$

Note that if $a\leq b\wedge b\leq a\Rightarrow a=b$ and

$a\leq b :\Leftrightarrow \exists c: a+c=b.$

Here if you take as underlying set the ring of integers, the field of rational, real or complex numbers, you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The book *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Elliot Mendelson, which was the textbook for my first course in mathematical logic, has a section on "First-Order Theories with Equality" starting on page 75. The book has two requirements for a theory with equality. The second requirement is that this is a theorem:

$$x=y \supset (\mathscr{A}(x,x) \supset \mathscr{A}(x,x))$$

where $x$ and $y$ are any variables, $\mathscr{A}(x,x)$ is any well-formed formula, and $\mathscr{A}(x,y)$ arises from $\mathscr{A}(x,x)$ by replacing some, but not necessarily all, free occurences of $x$ by $y$, with the proviso that $y$ is free for the occurences of $x$ which it replaces. (And of course, the "$\supset$" symbol means implication.) The name of this axiom schema is

> Substitutivity of Equality

Your property is a particular theorem included in this schema. The schema is a generalization of @J.G.'s answer, but it has a name.

Answer (score 0):

See : 
[Transforming equations : rules governing the use of '<=>' and '=>' .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167334/transforming-equations-rules-governing-the-use-of-and) and Mauro Allegranza's answer.

What follows is simply a development of J.G 's answer.

Define a function **f** , say from the set of real numbers  to the set of real numbers ,  such that f(x) = x+2;  that is, in terms of relation, f is the relation such that  :

f = {(x,y) | y = x + 2 }.

A relation R is a function iff :

no two different ordered pairs belonging to R have the same first element.

In other words, a relation R  is a function iff :

***all orders pairs belonging to R that have the same first element also have the same second element.***

Now, the ordered pairs ( a, z) and (b, z') such that z = a+2 and z'= b+2 belong to the function f .

These two pairs have the same first element, since, by hypothesis: a = b.

Consequently, they also have the same second element, which means that z = z'.

According to the definitions of z and of z', it means that :

```
                             a+2 = b+2
```